# Component Taking space instead of float above the other components when toggled

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to add a date range component in my existing reactjs material ui project.But problem is its taking space instead of just showing it "above other components" just like the Select component

Here's the example snippet I want to add in my app https://codesandbox.io/s/materialui-daterange-picker-2p3f1?file=/src/App.js:274-385

My actual implementation

```
 const Wow = () => (
    <DateRangePicker
      open={open}
      toggle={toggle}
      onChange={(range) => setDateRange(range)}
    />
 );
 const DateRange = () => (
  <>
    <Grid
      container
      spacing={1}
    >
      <Grid
        item
        lg={10}
        md={12}
        xl={9}
        xs={12}
      >
        <Button
          onClick={() => setOpen(true)}
        >
          Show
        </Button>
        <Wow />
      </Grid>
      <Grid
       item
       lg={2}
       md={12}
       xl={9}
       xs={12}
      >
        <Button
          variant="contained"
          startIcon={<CheckIcon />}
          onClick={handleSubmit}
        >
          Go
        </Button>
     </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </>
  );
  
  return (
   <>
    <Helmet>
      <title>Selectors | Clever Clicks</title>
    </Helmet>
    <Box
      sx={{
        backgroundColor: 'background.default',
        minHeight: '100%',
        py: 3
      }}
    >
    <Container maxWidth={false}>
      <Grid
        container
        spacing={1}
      >
        <Grid
          item
          lg={4}
          md={12}
          xl={9}
          xs={12}
        >
          <TextField
            id="standard-select-currency-native"
            select
            label="Market"
            onChange={handleMarket}
            SelectProps={{
              native: true,
            }}
            size="small"
            fullWidth
            helperText="Please select "
          >
            {marketplaces.map((option) => (
              <option key={option.value} value={option.value}>
                {option.label}
              </option>
            ))}
          </TextField>
        </Grid>
        <Grid
          item
          lg={4}
          md={12}
          xl={9}
          xs={12}
        >
          <TextField
            id="standard-select-currency-native"
            select
            label="Products"
            onChange={handleProduct}
            SelectProps={{
              native: true
            }}
            size="small"
            fullWidth
            helperText="Please select products"
            inputProps={{ style: { fontSize: 15, overflow: 'visible' } }}
          >
            <option value="All"> --All-- </option>
            {products.map((option) => (
              <option key={option.id} value={`${option.title},${option.seller_sku},${option.id}`}>
                {option.title}
              </option>
            ))}
          </TextField>
        </Grid>
        <Grid
          item
          lg={4}
          md={12}
          xl={9}
          xs={12}
        >
          <DateRange />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Container>
  </Box>
</>
);
};
```

Its taking space when button is click to show
[image]

if you noticed, the below components are "forced" to stretch. What I want is to make the date range calendars "float".
Any help?

Answer (score 0):

By default, the `DateRangePicker` component isn't going to have *absolute* position, which is what you need if you'd like to position the modal without taking up DOM space.

A generic example would be something like this:

```
.datePicker {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50vw;
}

<DateRangePicker
  className="datePicker"
  open={open}
  toggle={toggle}
  onChange={(range) => setDateRange(range)}
/>
```

Using this after modifying the `top` and `left` properties to your needs may work if you combine it with a few media queries to compensate for different screen sizes.

However, if you want a more dynamic approach, you can take a look at [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68561725/position-tooltip-div-with-variable-height-above-span-react/68562331#68562331)

NOTE: Keep in mind that if the parent container is position `relative`, the absolute positioning will be relative to that element.